# Solution verification for a diophantine equation

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

I am solving this diophantine equation:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(abc)^2$$
Since $a^3+b^3=c^2(a^2b^2-c)$, it is known that $a^3+b^3\geq c^2$. And yet we can get
$$\begin{align}a^3+b^3&\geq c^2 \\ a^2b^2c^2&\geq c^3+c^2 \\ (a^2b^2-1)^2&\geq c^2\\...\end{align}$$
Can we say that $a^3+b^3=(a^2b^2-1)^2$ in this case?
(2019 IMO shortlisted question)

Comment: We can get $ 2 \geq 1, 3 \geq 1$. Can we say that $ 2 = 1 $ in this case?

Comment: @CalvinLin but $a^3+b^3=(a^2b^2-1)^2$ comes from the original equation, whereas $2\ne 3$ is known.

Comment: Can you explain how it comes from the original equation? What's your working?

Comment: Because $a^3+b^3$ is a positive integer, and so do $c^2$, this shows that $a^2b^2-c$ is also a positive integer. And yet this comes the inequality $a^3=b^3\geq c^2$ and by adding both sides $c^3$ and changing of $a^3+b^3+c^3=(abc)^2$, we end up with the equation written.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand what you're trying to say. Can you edit your question with the details?